# How I can instantly replace presented UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented two different `UIViewControllers`, that should replace each other based on server respond and user actions. For simplicity let's think that we have two `UIViewControllers` with `button` *replace with another*, that should trigger this replacement.

Now I need to do that replace part, but the problem is there is some delay between dismissing one **screen** and showing the other. I want to somehow get rid of it. I show `UIViewController` modally with **present** `method`.

I thought about making these two screen as views in **xib**-files, and one `UIViewController` that will be loading these **xibs**, adding them as `subViews` and replacing one `subView` with another when it needs it, but maybe there is a way to do that with two `UIViewControllers`?

Code that I use to present controller:

```
let vc = UIViewController1()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And to dismiss:

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a container view and in that view you can simply add your desired controller as the child view controller
[official doc reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

[another reference](https://medium.com/@Dougly/creating-a-custom-view-controller-navigation-interface-programmatically-swift-3-1-8c9e582cdb30)

Answer (score 0):

Set the present method's "animate" parameter to be false

Comment: I'm already using present and dismiss methods with animate parameter set to be false

Answer (score 0):

- To **Present**

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

- To **Dismiss**

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

First you send *notification* to *parent class* for **present** another 'viewController' and then **dismiss** *current class*

- Note: Both present class method set animation false

Comment: yes, I already use those methods with animate parameter set to be false. But there is still some delay between screen replacement.